# git-svn: Keep single merge commit after svn rebase

Tags: git, git-svn

I am following this pattern to check in my code in feature-branch to Subversion with git-svn:

```
git checkout master
git svn rebase
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature-branch
git commit --amend
git svn dcommit
```

(master is my remote Subversion tracking branch)

This creates a single merge commit on master (regardless of how many git commits I have done on feature-branch) which I can check into Subversion.

However, someone checks code into Subversion after I merge feature-branch into master, when I execute the command `git svn rebase` the new changes are applied and each individual commit from feature-branch is applied on top.  At this point I no longer have a single merge commit but every commit that I performed on feature-branch in master.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Just FYI, there is no rule that you only push one commit at a time when doing dcommit. You can do several at a time (after cleaning up the history as you like it, like Spike suggests).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do this:

```
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase -i HEAD~10  # squash commits in my editor
git svn rebase  # make sure I have the latest code
git svn dcommit
git checkout master
git svn rebase # now the feature-branch squashed commit is visible on master
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do what you want by using the `--squash` option:

```
# rebase master and then feature-branch as above
git merge --squash feature-branch
git commit -m "Merge from feature-branch"
git svn dcommit
```

This avoids making feature-branch a parent of your new commit. It sounds like the multiple parents is confusing git-svn.